# Best practices for handling CORS between Spring and Angular JS?

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-security, cors

We are using Java Spring for building a rest api. And we are using angularjs for frontend. The rest api is in one domain and the angularjs is in another domain. Initially, when i tried to do a 'POST' request from angular to the rest api, it gave CORS error. Then we resolved this issue by setting up CORS filter at the backend. But when we tried to do a get request, it is throwing 401 unauthorized error. That's because, our get request is 'not-a-simple-request' as the request has content-type as application/json and headers have 'Authorization' (since we are using basic auhentication). So the browser sends a preflight 'OPTIONS' request to the server before sending the 'GET' request. And hence the 401 error is thrown for the 'OPTIONS' request by the Spring security by intercepting the url. And that's because the 'OPTIONS' request doesnt have any credentials. So to overcome this issue, we have placed method="GET" in intercept url in spring-security.xml. This has fixed the issue. But is this a good practice, specifying method in intercept url? And also is the process we are following, a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best practice, but we had the same issue and fixed it by setting the ROLE_ANONYMOUS specifically for the OPTIONS method in the `spring-security.xml`:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/users" method="OPTIONS" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
```